# windows fonts got overwritten

Tags: windows, fonts

My windows fonts got overwritten and are wrongly displayed in installed programs. I already tried control panel=>fonts=>font settings=>reset without success. For example in adobe acrobat reader it looks like this:

[image]

In chrome, it is displayed correctly:

[image]

Comment: Try [How to rebuild Font cache in Windows 10](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/rebuild-font-cache-in-windows).

Comment: did not work. even before restarting the two services, the fonts are the same as before

Comment: You will need then to identify the bad fonts and reinstall them.